# How to use Timeout Ticket Expiration Policy in CAS while client session cookie expires after session end?

Tags: java, session, single-sign-on, cas

I use CAS Java client 3.4.1 and CAS server 5.3.

As I understand after successful authentication CAS client adds data to client app's session. Now on every request CAS client verifies this data in session and if it's correct, request flow continues (no request is made to CAS server). But if session is missing or CAS attribute (_const_cas_assertion_) is missing from session, then CAS client makes request to CAS server to verify that user is authenticated. Now on that request CAS server updates it's TGT last used timestamp and TGT timeout is extended.

In my case client app's session cookie (JSESSIONID) expires when session ends (browser is closed for example). But when TGT expires lets say in 10 hours and user does not close it's browser in 10 hours then no request is made to CAS server and TGT expiration is not extended. But if user opens after 5 hours client2 app, then request is made to CAS server and TGT expiration is extended by 10 hours. That means SLO request is sent to client1 app after 15 hours.

My question is that how can I make client to update TGT last time used timestamp when it's using only client1 app without clearing client's session cookie or making client otherwise call authentication in CAS server again? I want to update TGT last time used timestamp if client app is opened (and used) and not closed in 10 hours so client would not be sent SLO request after 10 hours has passed (because TGT last used is 10 hours ago).

In other words how to extend the use of TGT when client is using app without clearing session?

Clearing session is not acceptable because then CAS client's AuthenticationFilter would initiate authentication which would redirect client's browser to CAS server and this would redirect it back to client app. It will redirect back to same page, but clients view state would be lost (for example in JSF ViewScoped bean).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that how can I make client to extend TGT timeout when it's using only client1 app without clearing client's session cookie or making client otherwise call authentication in CAS server again?

You cannot. A TGT timeout is global to the CAS deployment. Having a single application *somehow* extend that timeout would interfere and interrupt the same policy/timeout rule for other applications that may not want this extension. If a CAS server is set to timeout at 10 hours, that's a hard-stop and the session will end at 10 hours.

As a client application, you cant generally modify server behavior dynamically at random. That would defeat the purpose of centralization, centralized audits, security, etc and the behavior of other applications interacting with the same server.

> I want to extend TGT expiration if client app is opened (and used) and not closed in 10 hours so client would not be sent SLO request after 10 hours has passed.

Possibly, extend the SLO filter to not destroy the app if the session is still active, or remove the SLO filter from your application configuration if you don't want to participate in SLO...or contact your CAS server admins and discuss nuances of SLO with them.

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing. I updated my question to be more clear.
To clarify: I don't want to extend TGT timeout itself from client, I want to update TGT last time used timestamp from client side to use Timeout Ticket Expiration Policy in CAS server.
SLO works fine for me. If TGT is not used for 10 hours, then it should log client out. But if client is using application (but not making any calls to CAS server) then I would like client to be logged in up to 10 hours after last client application use timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Either way, as a client you cannot in any way update the TGT last-time used to keep it alive, in the event that your application is not making CAS calls. As I said, this will affect other client applications. If the CAS sessions times out while your application is still active, you need to add in the code so the SLO filter does not destroy an active application session, or disable SLO. Alternatively, modify the CAS server code to accommodate the task globally.

Comment: For me it seems a bit strange, when using https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-Ticket-Expiration-Policy.html#timeout Timeout policy.
Because lets say timeout is set to 10h and client1 uses TGT 10:00. Now if no other client uses the same TGT then client1 would be logged out 20:00.
But if client2 uses the TGT 13:00, then TGT last used timestamp is updated and both client1 and client2 would be logged out 23:00.
That way client2 affects client1. This is the current situation with this policy.